# $F'(z;v).v \geq b|v|^2$ involving a function $F:(x,y) \mapsto(x+f(y),y+f(x))$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ function, define 
$F:(x,y) \mapsto(x+f(y),y+f(x))$

I need to prove that if there exists a constant $0<a<1$ such that $|f'(x)|\leq a, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ then there exists another constant $0<b<1$ such that

$F'(z;v).v \geq b|v|^2$ for every $z,v\in \mathbb{R^2} $

$F'(z;v)$ denotes the directional derivative at z in the direction of v

I know that $F'(z;v).v=v_1^2+v_2^2+2v_1v_2 \frac{f'(x)+f'(y)}{2}$, but from here I don't know how I could obtain the correct inequality, everything I can think of gives me $F'(z;v).v \leq something$.

Any advices?

Comment: $F : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$. I'm unclear on what you mean by $F'$.

Comment: The directional derivative at $z$ in the direction of $v$

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\left| 2v_1 v_2 \left( \frac{f'(x) + f'(y)}{2} \right) \right| \le 2a |v_1| |v_2|$$ by hypothesis and
$$2a |v_1| |v_2| \le a(v_1^2 + v_2^2)$$
in light of the elementary inequality $xy \le \frac{x^2 + y^2}{2}$ whenever $x,y \ge 0$. You end up with, in turn,
$$\left| 2v_1 v_2 \left( \frac{f'(x) + f'(y)}{2} \right) \right| \le a(v_1^2 + v_2^2),$$
$$ 2v_1 v_2 \left( \frac{f'(x) + f'(y)}{2} \right)\ge - a(v_1^2 + v_2^2),$$
$$ v_1^2 + v_2^2  + 2v_1 v_2 \left( \frac{f'(x) + f'(y)}{2} \right)\ge (1- a)(v_1^2 + v_2^2),$$
$$ F'(x,y;v) \cdot v \ge (1-a)|v|^2.$$